# Can a Rust crate dependencies be installed globally?

Tags: rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I'm creating a monorepo using Nx, Rust and TS. The Rust code is divided in crates, and since I'm using Nx, I've not used Cargo Workspaces. The problem I'm facing now is that every re-install the dependencies of the crates it depends on, needlessly increasing the size of `target/debug/deps`.

I'm looking for a way to install/store the dependencies in a unified – probably global – location, that can reduce this dependency duplication, like [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) does for javascript. I know that cargo already caches the packages' source code globally, which is great, but it still stores the compiled objects in the `target/debug/deps`.

Comment: Check out sccache: https://crates.io/crates/sccache

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible but as @drewtato said you can use sccache to cache the crates to speed up build times. You can also try using a faster linker like mold to speed up linking

To use sccache (after installed):
(adapted from sccache readme)
Add this to your global cargo config `$HOME/.cargo/config.toml` or project cargo config `project/.cargo/config.toml`

```ini
[build]
rustc-wrapper = "/path/to/sccache"
```

You can also use the env var `export RUSTC_WRAPPER=/path/to/sccache`